# How do templates work in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

I've been working through the Discover meteor book, currently at chapter 6. I'm having great difficulty in understanding the relationship between templates, and how they work.

For example, I have a template called posts_lists.html and a javascript file called posts_lists.js

Within posts_lists.js I have the following:

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
  posts: postsData
});
```

And within posts_lists.html I have:

```
<template name="postsList">
  <div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

So, am I right in thinking that Template.postsList.helpers({ is a  block that contains all the variables accessed by the postsList template. The bock returns postsData in the form of posts.

posts is looped over - calling the postItem template. This is where I get lost... as I don't have a postItem.js file, or postItem.html file

I do have post_item.html and post_item.js - but these aren't named the same as postItem...

....but it works???? I don't get it. I know its not magic... but cant figure it out. In terms of my level / skillset I'm a designer / jquery user trying to learn more.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: So thinking about this, I've spoken with the JS dev's next door - and they said that meteor must look at everything within the folder and enumerate it. That the critical bit is the <template name=..>, not the file name (but it makes sense to name files / follow the naming conventions as the book advises - so I know what they're for). Is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file names have little significance. It's just a convention.

Your `post_item.html` should contain a template named `postItem`.

Comment: So does the .js file also have to have the same name as the .html file in order to work?

Comment: No. It can have any name you like. There are very few restrictions on file/folder names. The ones that come to mind are the `/server`, `/client` and `/lib` directories and the `main*` files.